# 2 NMOS in series, connected source to source

Tags: mosfet, series, nmos

I am working with DC2418A evaluation board (Link to datasheet is [HERE](https://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/evaluation-kit-manuals/DC2418A_UG-1382.pdf))

- Schematic is on page 5
- I am using version A, so we ignore Q1

My question is about Q2 and Q3: Why are they connected source to source? Q2 seems oriented properly, but Q3 seems like it should be flipped so current goes drain to source. I thought it might be because of a protection feature but I am not sure.

Any help is appreciated. Here is the portion of the circuit I am talking about (schematic taken from datasheet)

[image: Input to output]

Answer (score 1):

Because of the body diodes in most MOSFETs, they will conduct in one direction (with a diode drop) even when switched off.  Putting them back-to-back like this allows you to control current flow in both directions.

The source seems to be floating, but there's enough leakage to keep it in the neighborhood of whichever side is higher when off.

Comment: I don't believe the sources are floating for Q2 and Q3. It looks like current goes from: Vin to drain of Q2 then to source of Q2, then from source of Q3 (also source of Q2) to drain of Q3 then to output

Comment: a double arrangement makes sure that the mosfets can effectively isolate, without their body diodes conducting, in any configuration.

Comment: @Eric - do not let your lack of belief blind you to reality. If by "drain to source" youi mean via the FET itself then by that measure EVERYTHING is connected together. The idea of reverse piolarity back to back FETs is as you have been told here by others. Understand them and you have your answer. [I have had a few hundred thousand devices built  with this arrangement in them.]

Comment: Thanks Cristobol and Mehmet for the helpful explanation and comments.